# exit or close the vim through shell script

Tags: linux, vim

I'm writing a script file in which I have to close the vim files that are opened. So, how can I close or exit from the file through the shell script? I've tried this [solution](https://superuser.com/questions/451863/how-to-run-vim-command-from-the-shell), but had no luck. I've tried it this way:

```
vim path_to_file/abc +qa
```

Comment: `vim` is not a server. It's not designed to listen to commands given by random shell scripts.

Comment: @n.m. It _is_ supposed to enable commands to be run automatically when it’s started, by means of (for example) `+`, as described in the question. :)

Comment: Please give more background; what is your final goal? When a question is only about a small technical step, it's difficult to provide a good answer. If you don't tell us **why** you want this, it's easy to succumb to the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @ebenezer vim can run a vim script. The question is about something else.

Comment: I assume that you have proper reason to do that, even though I think it doesn't make much sense.  what if your vim has opened 10 files, but all of them in "changed but not yet saved" status? vim can do some automatic text process, receiving your commands from cmd-line. but it is not what is good at. it is an Editor after all. If you really want to do that, I guess (not tested), you can get the pid of which vim opened your file opened (lsof), then kill the vim.

Comment: @n.m. From the question: “how can I close or exit from the file through the shell script?” [An answer on that SuperUser question](http://superuser.com/a/451865/230861) describes how this can be done with Vim (and in fact, I am able to do this, using `+q`).

Comment: @ebenezer This is linked directly from the question. This is not what the OP needs.

Comment: @n.m. Sorry — I must have misunderstood something. I realized that that was linked to from the question; that was my point. :) I was only trying to say that that answer described what this question is asking for, but again, I must have misunderstood.

Comment: @ebenezer I *think* Ingo Karkat's answer is what the OP needs (because vim *is* apparently a server).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to close an existing, running Vim from an external shell script, you either have to tell that Vim instance to quit, or let the operating system do the job.

#### communication with Vim

Vim has client-server functionality built in, see `:help remote.txt`. If you know the *server name* (you can get the list with `vim --serverlist`), you can send it commands. E.g. this tells the Vim instance named `GVIM` to quit:

```
$ vim --servername GVIM --remote-send '<C-\><C-N>:quitall!<CR>'
```

#### through operating system

Brute force: kill **all** running Vim instances :-)

```
$ killall vim
```

To find the Vim instance which has a particular file open, the `lsof` tool can be used. Because Vim only opens the file itself on `:write`s, we have to search for its (permanently open) *swap file* (i.e. `.file.swp` instead of `file`):

```
$ kill `lsof -t /path/to/.file.swp`
```